# Search for a precise number with grep

Tags: grep

I am trying to look for lines in a file that have one or more instances of `1234`, but no other numbers (non-digit characters are allowed). Any other number should cause the line not to match.

Valid examples:

- `1234`
- `1234 xxx`
- `xxx 1234`
- `1234 1234`
- `1234 xxx 1234`

Invalid examples:

- `12341234`
- `12345`
- `1234xxx345`
- `1234 345`
- `1234xxx`
- `xxx1234`
- `1234xxx1234`

This is what I have used:

```
grep -E '^([^0-9]*1234)+[^0-9]*$' file.txt
```

But this command also outputs 12341234 as valid, how do I prevent that?

Comment: I edited to add more examples, as I understand it. Please re-edit if I have erred.

Comment: It seems to me that `12341234` has two instances of `1234` and no other numbers — so why is it invalid?

Comment: @G-Man, I think because `12341234` constitutes a number that is different than `1234`

Comment: @G-Man I guess because there needs to be non-digit characters between the two `1234`? Presumably OP considers `12341234` as one number (in the first paragraph).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -E '^[^0-9]*1234([^0-9]+1234)*[^0-9]*$' file.txt
```

### Explanation

- `^[^0-9]*1234`: find the first match of `1234`, which may be preceded by non-digit characters.
- `([^0-9]+1234)*`: there may be further iterations of `1234`, but these must be separated from the first `1234` (and other `1234`) by non-digit characters (hence use `+`).
- `[^0-9]*$`: match the entire line (with `$`). There may be non-digit characters after the final `1234` (but not necessarily, hence `*`).

## EDIT

If `1234` must be delimited by spaces (or be at the beginning or end of the line), then use

```
grep -E '^([^0-9]* )?1234(( [^0-9]*)? 1234)*( [^0-9]*)?$'
```

### Explanation

- `^([^0-9]* )?`: there may be non-digit characters to start with, as long as they end with a space.
- `1234`: find the first (required) match of `1234`.
- `(( [^0-9]*)? 1234)*`: I'll work through the parentheses backwards. There may be (zero or more) further copies of `1234`, but these must be preceded by a space, i.e. `1234`. Before this space, there may be non-digit characters, which is fine as long as these are separated from the preceding copy of `1243` by another space, i.e.`( [^0-9]*)?`.
- `( [^0-9]*)?$`: there may be non-digit characters to end with, as long as they are preceded by a space.

Comment: `([^0-9]+1234)?` is more correct in the case but `grep -Ex '[^0-9]*(1234)[^0-9]*(|[^0-9]\1)'` shorter.

Comment: @Costas I don't quite understand where the first code goes. The second doesn't seem to work either. It would fail to match (e.g.) `1234 1234 1234`.

Comment: As I understand `1234 1234 1234` shouldnot match just double like `1234 1234`

Comment: but if you'd like `grep -Ex '[^0-9]*(1234)[^0-9]*([^0-9]\1)*'`

Comment: @Costas The question says "one or more instances". Also, your code now fails on `'1234 1234x'`

Comment: You say «fail» but I say «as expected» — it depends of the task

Comment: @Costas Surely `1234 1234x` is consistent with "one or more instances of 1234, but no other numbers (non-digit characters are allowed)"?

Comment: @Sparhawk As per the question  1234 1234x is not valid as it 1234x != 1234, but your answer matches it. how to prevent this?, thanks

Comment: @Costas Thanks for your command, but it fails in the case when we have: 1234 1234 hi, how can you handle this?

Comment: Even easy `grep -Ex '[^0-9]*(1234)([^0-9](|\1))*'`

Comment: @KLMM I think there is a fair bit of confusion as to what patterns should be accepted and what should not. I (previously) edited the question to clarify, but perhaps I did it wrong. What should the `1234`s be delimited with? I thought it was anything that was not a digit, but is that incorrect?

Comment: @Sparhawk for example: 1234 1234 x is valid but 1234 1234x is invalid

Comment: @KLMM Okay, then you'll need to edit your question.

Comment: @Sparhawk I have edited the question to be more clear, can you also edit your answer to satisfy this, so that I can select your answer

Comment: @KLMM I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Sparhawk this doesn't work: 'hey its 1234,  1234'

Comment: @KLMM Again, you didn't mention this case in your question! We can only answer according to the information you provide. Hence, please list all the possible variations. So `,` is fine directly after `1234`. What about directly before? What other characters are allowed?

Answer (score 5):

`awk` might be handier than `grep` at this.
Set the field separator to runs of non-digit characters, then loop through fields and only print line if every non-empty field is exactly equal to `1234`

```
awk -F'[^[:digit:]]+' '{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; ++i) 
  if (($i) && ($i != 1234)) next
  }; {print}' file.txt
```

Comment: Huh… clever! +1

Answer (score 3):

Search for the number either at the beginning of the  (`^`) line or preceded by a non-digit (`[^0-9]`), and likewise at the end (`$` or `[^0-9]`).

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])1234($|[^0-9])' file.txt
```

If you want to allow leading zeros, add `0*` before the number.

```
grep -E '(^|[^0-9])0*1234($|[^0-9])' file.txt
```

If you also want to reject lines containing any sequence of one or more digits that isn't part of an occurrence of this particular number, then you're looking for lines consisting of sequences alternating one or more nondigits and that particular number, which is basically `([^0-9]+1234)*`. The line may start and end with either the number or a nondigit, whereas internal sequences of nondigits may not be empty. Furthermore the line must contain the number at least once. Putting it all together:

```
grep -xE '[^0-9]*1234([^0-9]+1234)*[^0-9]*' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't think the condition that no other numbers are allowed is being satisfied. for example: 20300 1234 is invalid but it matches with the command, how to handle this case?

Comment: @KLMM This finds the line since it does contain `1234`. Do you want to exclude lines that contain any other number? That wasn't stated in your question.

Comment: yes i mentioned in the question : "but no other numbers", all numbers except 1234 shouldn't be matched

Comment: nice, but this would fail the case when no numbers are present at all, for example: "hi how are you " would be matched with it but it should be exempted

Comment: And is it possible to do the negation without using the -xE flag ? by using ^?

Comment: @KLMM `-x` is a shortcut for putting `^` at the beginning of the regexp and `$` at the end. If for some reason you don't like `-x`, use `^` and `$` instead. There's no negation involved.

Comment: The last **grep**script remain lines with no-numbers symbols. Better `grep -Ex '[^0-9]*(1234)[^0-9]*(|[^0-9]\1)'`